# How to divide a line so that its division points coincide with two points on the line?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

Say I have a segment AB, and on this line there are two points p1 and p2. I want to equally divide the line in such a way that equal divisions land on these two points simultaneously. How is this done? I want to plug in different values of divisions until I get close to certain number, i.e., I want the equally spaced division segments to hit a target length within a range that also hits these points perfectly.

So, for example, in the image below you can see two parallel line segments passing through the top left and bottom right of the unit square. The line segment that is perpendicular to these two lines (slightly offset from the diagonal of the square) needs to be divided equally in such a way that the, as I said, division points intersect perfectly with the two interior parallel line segments that stretch out to the top right.

[image]

Here you can see my selected slope of 56 degrees, and equally spaced divisions stepping down from 10, 9, 8, etc. Notice that the perpendicular line segment between the two parallel line segments that pass through the top left and bottom right corner of the square can be divided into 5 or 10 segments and have the division points (circled in red) almost intersect the two "points" on said line where the two interior line segments intersect.

I hope it is clear that I am trying to isolate the essence of the problem even though it is in fact part of another problem.

Divide the line into k segments of length d such that there exists some positive integers $n_1$ and $n_2$ to hit the points $P_1 = (x_1,0)$ and $P_2 = (x_2,0)$ like this:

$$P_1 = (n_1 d,0), P_2 = (n_2 d,0)$$

Comment: Not exactly sure what you are asking: do you want a procedure to divide the p1-p2 segment in equal parts, say 5? Is this a procedure to use straight edges and compass?

Comment: @Loie Benedcte , the length of the line must be a multiple of $P_1P_2$, or the length of line and measure of $P_1P_2$ must have a common divisor, in this case the measure of each part is equal to common divisor.

Comment: @Andrei, I want to divide AB into equal parts in such a way that the division point coincides with P1 and P2 simultaneously.

Comment: It makes a difference whether $AB$ denotes a *line* or a *line segment*.  For a line (as you wrote), the two points $p_1,p_2$ (distinct?) give a natural line segment on $AB$ that can be used to give equal length sections that partition the line.

Comment: It might not be possible. Say the length of $AB$ is an irrational number, but the length of $P_1P_2$ is rational. Then any subdivision of $P_1P_2$ is rational, so an integer number of such subdivision will be a rational number, which can't be equal to $AB$

Answer (score 0):

Draw a line through $A$, at some angle with $AB$. Then use a compass to mark a point $C_1$ on this line, at some arbitrary distance $d$ from $A$. Then continue with $C_2$, at distance $d$ from $C_1$, and so on, until $n$, your number of desired intervals along $AB$. Now draw the $C_nB$ line. Through each of the $C_i$ points, draw parallel lines to $C_nB$. See for example https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=im81vHIhZS8 Each of this line will intersect the $AB$ line in points $D_i$. You form a series of similar triangles, so the distance between these intersections are the same.
Something like [image]

Comment: Your post illustrates that for any positive integer $n$, a line segment $AB$ can be equally divided into $n$ subsegments by a ruler-and-compass construction.  However you make no mention of the points $p_1$ and $p_2$ in the Question, so it isn't obvious that this addresses the originally posed problem.  Indeed if the distance between $p_1$ and $p_2$ is incommensurate with the length of $AB$, it ostensibly is not possible to do what the problem asks.

Comment: @hardmath, vote to reopen.